# What is the efficient way to copy large database from one server to another?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backup, database-replication

I have a SQL server's full database backup job that runs daily at night.

Currently, I need to stay up late every night to copy that backup file (around 300GB in size) to 5 servers in different locations over the Internet via FTP. I use FileZilla but sometimes the copy job unexpectedly fails, therefore I need to start from scratch.

Could you please give me more efficient ways to do this automatically? Thank you so much in advanced.

Comment: What is your OS? What is your database?

Comment: I guess without paid softwares, replication or incremented backup will be good choice for any database.

Comment: @RomeoNinov My OS is Windows Server 2016, the version of SQL Server is 17 (Enterprise Edition).

Comment: You could look into a remote backup where you specify the target location in the backup command using a UNC path.  That way, it would write the backup directly to the locations for you automatically.